# Autoresizing of UILabels in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I am adding my own `UILabel`s to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell` because I need more control over the layout than the default UITableViewCellStyles provide.  In essence I want the detailLabel have priority over the textLabel so the textLabel gets truncated.

I have the following code in my `UITableViewController`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString * const kCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

  UITableViewCell * cell =
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];

  UILabel * titleLabel, * dateLabel;

  if(cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
        reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    titleLabel.tag = kTitleLabelTag;
    titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    dateLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateLabel.tag = kDateLabelTag;
    dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    dateLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
  }

  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)pCell
  atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)pIndexPath
{
  const float kHeight = 44.0, kLeftIndent = 8.0, kOverallWidth = 293.0,
      kGap = 1.0;

  UILabel * titleLabel, * dateLabel;
  titleLabel = (UILabel *)[pCell.contentView viewWithTag:kTitleLabelTag];
  dateLabel = (UILabel *)[pCell.contentView viewWithTag:kDateLabelTag];

  NSString * dateText = @"9:39 AM";

  // Calculate the size of dateLabel
  CGSize dateSize = [dateText sizeWithFont:[dateLabel font]
      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(kOverallWidth, kHeight)];

  const float dateXPos = kOverallWidth - dateSize.width;
  dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(dateXPos, 0.0, dateSize.width, kHeight);
  titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(kLeftIndent, 0.0,
      dateXPos - kLeftIndent - kGap, kHeight);

  titleLabel.text = @"Some potentially very long text which will be wrapped.";
  dateLabel.text = dateText;
  pCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
}
```

The code above produces incorrect results.  When the table view is initially shown, it looks like figure 1) in [this image of the renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwaeE.png).

So there is a **unwanted gap on the right** of all the `dateLabel`s. (the purple background is just for better visibility what is going on)

When dragging the tableview up like in 2) in the image, it then bounces back and looks like 3).

**The first row has now exactly the layout I wanted** and which calculated in `configureCell:atIndexPath:`.  I guess this behavior happens because the cells get re-used and then configured again.

So it feels like I am missing some kind of initialization, I have tried calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutSubviews` of `pCell` and `pCell.contentView` but never achieved an initial correct rendering.

Only when I set the `autoresizingMask` of `titleLabel` and `dateLabel` to `UIViewAutoresizingNone` I get a correct initial rendering, then however the swipe to delete does not work because the delete button gets rendered over the `dateLabel`.

What do I have to change in my code so that all cells get *rendered initially* like the first cell in the third picture?

Thanks!

PS: I would like to have inlined the pictures but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation for that.

Comment: +1 for working with `const float` instead of `#define` for better type safety. I know in Apple's sample code they often use precompiler directives but using consts is better. IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good, and maybe simpler way to do this is to:

First Create a custom UITableViewCell subclass which you can setup using Interface Builder. If "MyTableViewCell" is your custom cell view you initialize it in CellForRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
MyTableViewCellClass *cell = (MyTableViewCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCellClass"] autorelease];

if (!cell)
cell = [[[MyTableViewCellClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCellClass"] autorelease];

// Call specific methods on your cell to pass information to it, not for display
[cell setProperties:...];
```

Then implement the layoutSubviews method in your custom UITableViewCell subclass. For instance:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
// You must call this first to make sure your cell gets current parent information
[super layoutSubviews];

// Retrieve the content view bounds. This will include the edit symbols when present (delete button and ordering symbol
float inset = 5.0;
CGRect bounds = [[self contentView] bounds];

// Keep on going here with your own view layout.

}
```

Doing this you basically separate the cell model (CellForRowAtIndexPath) from the cell view (your custom implementation of cell drawing). If you later change the implementation (layout) of your cell you can do this easily simply by changing your cell layout without worrying about the CellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Thank you!  Doing the code from `configureCell:` in a `layoutSubviews` method of a subclass and then using `bounds.size.width` instead of my fixed `kOverallWidth` solved it.

Comment: @Torsten Glad it helped. Good luck with the app.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with a **storyboard** , you should disable the "Use Auto Layout" in the File Inspector!

Then set the cell's property **autoresizesSubviews**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    self.autoresizesSubviews=YES;

}
```

The final step is configure the frame of the Label , overriding  the method **layoutSubviews** of the UITableViewCell class

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{

    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat top=VerticalPadding;
    CGFloat left=HorizentalPadding;
    CGFloat width=CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)-2*HorizentalPadding;
    CGFloat height=CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)-2*VerticalPadding;
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(left, top, width, height);
    self.Label.frame=rect;

}
```